# how to php variable value assign as java script

Tags: php

```
<script>
var id=`$`php;
</script>
```

I've added php variable store as JavaScript.
but some thing wrong in my code. what wrong with there please help me

Comment: How to inject `php` variable into `javascript`. Question number 10000000? Seriously, use search. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/java script">
var id='<?php echo $id;?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need PHP tags around the variable name and you need to use `echo` to print out the value

```
<script>
  var id = <?php echo $whatever; ?>;
</script>
```

Use quotes if it's a string

Comment: You could also use the shorthand `<?= $whatever ?>` provided that the PHP interpreter has those enabled.

Comment: @izuriel Let's give general answers, if we consider such things we can write an answer with 100 combinations

Comment: I did make it a comment, and not contribute to the multitude of answers here - in other words. I added on additional information. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @izuriel Oh that's dfine, I thought you are telling me to add it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
<script>
var id=<?php echo $var;?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    var id= <?php echo $php;?>;
</script>
```